# Not able to configure Spring Boot with Cucumber having more than one step files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber

I have a `Cucumber-Selenium` based test written using `Spring Boot`. The problem is that if I have just one step definition file `GoolgeCalcStepDefinition.java` then the program works and test passes without any issue but as soon as I added `BingSearchStepDefinition.java` along with feature file then I get following error.

I googled around on how to configure `Spring Boot` with `Cucumber` but most of the examples/articles available online shows only one step definition file.

**mvn verify**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.TestRunner
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.368 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.TestRunner
initializationError(com.example.TestRunner)  Time elapsed: 0.004 sec  <<< ERROR!
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Glue class class com.example.stepdefs.GoogleCalcStepDefinition and class com.example.stepdefs.BingSearchStepDefinition both attempt to configure the spring context. Please ensure only one glue class configures the spring context


Results :

Tests in error:
  TestRunner.initializationError » Cucumber Glue class class com.example.stepdef...

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to I:\pet-projects\junit-cucumber-demo\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) @ junit-cucumber-demo ---
[INFO] Building jar: I:\pet-projects\junit-cucumber-demo\target\junit-cucumber-demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.0.6.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ junit-cucumber-demo ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-cucumber-reporting:3.14.0:generate (execution) @ junit-cucumber-demo ---
ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.
[INFO] About to generate Cucumber report.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.718 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-04-14T16:04:55-04:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**TestRunner.java**

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty", "json:target/cucumber-reports/cucumber.json"},
        glue = {"com.example.stepdefs"},
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"})
public class TestRunner {

}
```

**DemoApplicationTests.java**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class DemoApplicationTests {

}
```

**GoogleCalcStepDefinition.java**

```
@Ignore
public class GoogleCalcStepDefinition extends DemoApplicationTests {

    WebDriver driver;
    GoogleSearchPage googleSearchPage;

    @Given("^I open Google$")
    public void I_open_google() {
        this.driver = BrowserConfig.getWebDriver();
        this.googleSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, GoogleSearchPage.class);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String input) {
        googleSearchPage.searchBox.sendKeys(input); //passing 2+2 and 5*5 here
        googleSearchPage.searchBtn.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result(String expectedResult) {
        String result = googleSearchPage.calculatorTextBox.getText();
        assertEquals(result, expectedResult); //Verify that result of 2+2 is 4 and 5*5 is 25
        BrowserConfig.releaseResources(driver);
    }

}
```

**BingSearchStepDefinition.java**

```
@Ignore
public class BingSearchStepDefinition extends DemoApplicationTests {

    WebDriver driver;
    BingSearchPage bingSearchPage;

    @Given("^I open Bing$")
    public void I_open_bing() {
        this.driver = BrowserConfig.getWebDriver();
        this.bingSearchPage = PageFactory.initElements(driver, BingSearchPage.class);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.bing.com");
    }

    @When("^I enter \"([^\"]*)\" in search textbox$")
    public void I_enter_in_search_textbox(String input) {
        bingSearchPage.searchBox.sendKeys(input); //passing searchTerm = Ostrich
        bingSearchPage.searchBtn.click();
    }

    @Then("^I should get result as \"([^\"]*)\"$")
    public void I_should_get_correct_result(String input) {
        String result = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("result: " + result);
        assertEquals(result, input); //Verify that result = Bing - <searchTerm>
        BrowserConfig.releaseResources(driver);
    }

}
```

**google.feature**

```
Feature: Check addition in Google calculatorcontent
  In order to verify that Google calculator work correctly
  As a user of Google
  I should be able to get correct addition result

  Background: Do some arithmetic on Google
    Given I open Google

  Scenario: Addition
    When I enter "2+2" in search textbox
    Then I should get result as "4"

  Scenario: Multiplication
    When I enter "5*5" in search textbox
    Then I should get result as "25"
```

**bing.feature**

```
Feature: Check search in Bing
  In order to verify that Bing search works correctly
  As a user of Bing
  I should be able to get correct search result

  Scenario: Bird
    Given I open Bing
    When I enter "Ostrich" in search textbox
    Then I should get page title result as Bing " - Ostrich"
```

**pom.xml**

```
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

     <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.45.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: how did you solved  it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your runner classes extend `DemoApplicationTests.java` which is itself a `@SpringBootTest`.
Cucumber cannot determine which `SpringBootContext` to load when it fires up..  remove the class extends from your stepdefs and have `TestRunner` extend `DemoApplicationTests` instead

Comment: No, I think he should put the `@SpringBootTest` annotation to one of the step definition classes instead of the `TestRunner` class.

Comment: I am facing the same problem but removing the "extend integrationTest( which has @SpringBootTest)" from step classes gives me compile error as I am referring to some @Autowired beans declared in integrationTest class (same as DemoApplicationClass in main question above)